# Struts 2 library was not identifying when I was placed under the "Java Resources\Libraries" folder why?

Tags: java, struts2

When I was developing Struts2 application, I was getting

> Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter",

for this reason I was changed the filter to `FilterDispatcher` also. Then also I got same error. For that I placed the same jar files in `WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` folder then it was working fine. I didn't get why this was happening. Any one help.

Comment: `FilterDispatcher` is old (Struts 2.0). `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` is new. You cannot "change" one to another because "it doesn't work", you have to pickup the right version according to your Struts2 version. Then download all the needed libraries, and put them in the right place. Then if you still have problems, update the question

Comment: As a usual thing you should not put libraries to the `WEB-INF/lib` manually as this might be not the place that used to run your application. For better choice read the server documentation that enables you to manage the web applications deployed on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what all lib you have in your class path.Please have a look at [Strut2 simple-setup](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/simple-setup.html) which explains what all required dependencies you need to have to run application.

Alternatively best way to download [sample application](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts2314) from Struts2 official site and run it, to have a look at what all is required to run it.

It seems like you are missing `struts2-core.jar` though this error can be due to other reasons

Comment: I have solves the problem by placing jar files in WEB-INF\lib folder. But my question is why the IDE is not recognizing when I was placed the jar files by using build path -> configure build path option. 4

Comment: it should be. just clean and rebuilt it.

Comment: I got solution from the above mentioned exception but my doubt is this problem solved only when I was place jar files in lib folder only, when I use the option "build path-> configure build path" option I got this problem.

Comment: In end your jars should be in lib folder since web server will look at this specific place only and generally we place files in lib folder and build/configure path using your IED

Comment: I have tried clean and build option and tomcat working directory also cleaned but same problem repeated.

Comment: @Div The reason it doesn't work if they're only part of the build path is that the *application container* expects to have them at the normal Java EE servlet spec library location, which is `WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, the webserver will pick up class files from jars kept at `WEB_INF\lib` and other class files kept at `WEB_INF\classes` directory.